# cmake : add_library and dynamic targets list

Tags: cmake

I am trying to create a CMake macro that links to a set of "OBJECT" libraries/targets. But no way I can manage to make it work. The Visual Studion project is generated but there is no reference to the `.lib` files!

Does someone has an idea please?

When I display the content of "targets_list" I have this:

```
$<TARGET_OBJECTS:base>;$<TARGET_OBJECTS:graphics>;$<TARGET_OBJECTS:geodesy>;$<TARGET_OBJECTS:map>
```

Here is the code:

```
macro(AddSubProject project_name project_folder)
    ...
    # Links
    list(APPEND targets_list "")

    foreach (module ${ARGV2})
        list(APPEND targets_list $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${module}>)
    endforeach ()

    add_library(${project_name} SHARED ${_source_list} ${targets_list})
endmacro()
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a formatting issue in SO :-P

Comment: Why you expect linking with `.lib` files? These are *STATIC* libraries, not an *OBJECT* files. Object files have `.o` extension.

Comment: The other targets are build with : add_library(${project} OBJECT ${src}), I'm looking for a way to "link" all theses into my DLL ! (What is strange is that I also have the .lib file for the object targets, I don't know why !)

Comment: `I'm looking for a way to "link" all theses into my DLL` - You have done this, there is no problem in your current code. Just try to use resulted `.dll` library.

Comment: I also expect that it works, all the .obj are created but when I open Visual Studio I don't see anything that will include the .obj into my DLL. In fact, my DLL is not built because there are missing functions during the link !

Comment: So *OBJECT* libraries are simply not work for you. Provide [mcve]: with **exact** `CMakeLists.txt`, without unneded macro and `foreach()`, with exact error message and so on. (If it works for you without `foreach()`, show exact code which works and one which doesn't).